# pandas_merge asof throws "ValueError: left keys must be sorted" even though the DataFrame was sorted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

There are two dataframes df1 and df2 with common columns 'id' and 'time'. I would like to do left merge and for each id and time in df1, find the row with closest time for the same id from df2 and merge it to df1. Tried the code below but there is an error. How to resolve it?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'datetime': ['2022-01-01 01:00:00', '2022-01-01 02:00:00', '2021-01-02 01:00:00', '2022-01-03 01:00:00', '2022-01-04 01:00:00'], 'val1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                'datetime': ['2022-01-01 03:00:00', '2022-01-01 04:00:00', '2022-01-02 02:00:00', '2022-01-03 03:00:00', '2022-01-04 02:00:00', '2022-01-04 03:00:00'],
                'val2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
# convert datetime columns to datetime dtype
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime'])
df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime'])

# sort dataframes by id and datetime
df1 = df1.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'])

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='datetime', by='id', direction='nearest')

ValueError: left keys must be sorted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you should sort by 'datetime' first:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['datetime', 'id'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(['datetime', 'id'])
```

`merge_asof` works now:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='datetime', by='id', direction='nearest')

   id            datetime  val1  val2
0   2 2021-01-02 01:00:00    30   300
1   1 2022-01-01 01:00:00    10   100
2   1 2022-01-01 02:00:00    20   100
3   3 2022-01-03 01:00:00    40   400
4   4 2022-01-04 01:00:00    50   500
```

The reason this works is because it expects the 'datetime' column to be completely sorted (regardless of id). This was not the case when you initially sorted by 'id' first (only datetimes for a specific id were sorted WRT to each other but the datetime columns as a whole were not).