# Pandas `merge_asof` generating error - ValueError: left keys must be sorted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes that I'd like to merge using `merge_asof` -

```
import pandas as pd

data_0 = {'setting':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        'values': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0,1,2,3, 5,6]
        }

df_0 = pd.DataFrame(data_0)

print(df_0)
```

```
    setting  values
0         0       0
1         0       1
2         0       2
3         0       3
4         1       0
5         1       1
6         1       2
7         2       0
8         2       1
9         2       2
10        2       3
11        2       5
12        2       6
```

```
data_1 = {'setting':[0,1,2,2],
        'start_value': [1,0,1,3],
        'end_value':[3,2,3,6]
        }
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)

print(df_1)
```

```
   setting  start_value  end_value
0        0            1          3
1        1            0          2
2        2            1          3
3        2            3          6
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77380207/11628437) answer, I wrote the following code -

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(df_0.reset_index().sort_values(by=['setting', 'values']),
                     df_1.sort_values(by=['setting','start_value']),
                     by='setting', left_on='values', right_on='start_value')
         .query('values < end_value')
         .set_index('index').sort_index()
         .rename(columns={'values': 'values_from_data_0'})
      )

print(out)
```

However, I changed the sorting process slightly. Now, I am getting this error -

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8ab16dcd6572> in <cell line: 20>()
     18 
     19 
---> 20 out = (pd.merge_asof(df_0.reset_index().sort_values(by=['setting', 'values']),
     21                      df_1.sort_values(by=['setting','start_value']),
     22                      by='setting', left_on='values', right_on='start_value')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_join_indexers(self)
   2035                 raise ValueError(f"Merge keys contain null values on {side} side")
   2036             else:
-> 2037                 raise ValueError(f"{side} keys must be sorted")
   2038 
   2039         if not Index(right_values).is_monotonic_increasing:

ValueError: left keys must be sorted
```

While it seems that multi-column sorting is not the right way to go, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76022878/11628437) answer suggests to use multi-column sorting whereas there are other answers that suggest to sort only by the required column. Can someone clarify what's the right process to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `by='setting'`, you don't need to sort your dataframe by this column:

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(df_0.reset_index().sort_values(by='values'),
                     df_1.sort_values(by='start_value'),
                     by='setting', left_on='values', right_on='start_value')
         .query('values < end_value')
         .set_index('index').sort_index()
         .rename(columns={'values': 'values_from_data_0'})
      )
```

Output:

```
>>> out

       setting  values_from_data_0  start_value  end_value
index                                                     
1            0                   1          1.0        3.0
2            0                   2          1.0        3.0
4            1                   0          0.0        2.0
5            1                   1          0.0        2.0
8            2                   1          1.0        3.0
9            2                   2          1.0        3.0
10           2                   3          3.0        6.0
11           2                   5          3.0        6.0
```

Your code is equivalent to:

```
out = (df_0.reset_index().merge(df_1, on='setting')
           .query("(start_value <= values) & (values < end_value)")
           .set_index('index'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if my code is equivalent to this, ```out = (df_0.reset_index().merge(df_1, on='setting').query("(start_value <= values) & (values < end_value)").set_index('index'))```, why does it throw an error? There isn't anything semantically wrong with it.

Comment: Both codes work for me and give the same output (on your example). What is the error with `merge`?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Basically, `merge_asof` doesn't need me to sort by `'setting'` if I am doing `by=setting`. Got it.